# Initializing DataTables that has the markup inside javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatables

I am running into a problem here. I parse a `.CSV` file and I need to show them into a DataTables format.

The problem is The markups are all inside javascript as shown below

```
    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.xlsx|.xls)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = $("<table id='comp-monitor' class='table table-condensed table-striped'> \n\
            <tr><th>No.</th><th>DESKRIPSI ASSEMBLY</th><th>Drawing No.</th><th>QTY3</th><th>WEIGHT</th><th>-</th></tr>");
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    var no = 0;
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        no++;
//                        console.log(i);
                        var row = $("<tr />");
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                        // Column No
                        var cell_no = $("<td />");
                        cell_no.html(no);
                        row.append(cell_no);

                        for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                            var cell = $("<td />");
                            cell.html(cells[j]);
                            row.append(cell);
                        }

                        table.append(row);
                    }
                    $("#dvCSV").html('');
                    $("#dvCSV").append(table);
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);

            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }

    });
```

and the jquery initialization is just outside that function

```
$('#comp-monitor').DataTable();
```

Somehow the datatables doesn't run and I need some help with this where to put the initialization.

Thanks a bunch,

Comment: do you get any error msg?

Comment: no error. its just the data doesnt fill up and show as a datatable format

Answer (score 3):

You can Initialize the datatable inside javascript itself

```
$("#upload").bind("click", function () {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.xlsx|.xls)$/;
    if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
        if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
                var table = $("<table id='comp-monitor' class='table table-condensed table-striped'> \n\
            <tr><th>No.</th><th>DESKRIPSI ASSEMBLY</th><th>Drawing No.</th>    <th>QTY3</th><th>WEIGHT</th><th>-</th></tr>");
                var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                var no = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    no++;
//                        console.log(i);
                    var row = $("<tr />");
                    var cells = rows[i].split(",");

                    // Column No
                    var cell_no = $("<td />");
                    cell_no.html(no);
                    row.append(cell_no);

                    for (var j = 0; j < cells.length; j++) {
                        var cell = $("<td />");
                        cell.html(cells[j]);
                        row.append(cell);
                    }

                    table.append(row);
                }
                $("#dvCSV").html('');
                $("#dvCSV").append(table);
//HERE
               $('#comp-monitor').DataTable();

            }
            reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);

        } else {
            alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
        }
    } else {
        alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
    }

});
```

let me know if this work.

Comment: It doesnt work.. it shows the data table when i enter the page but when i click upload the data doesnt fill up the datatable

Comment: @KonzMama You can try Using the **onloadend()** on _reader_ object and inside that initialize the datatable as `reader.onloadend = function(e){ $('#comp-monitor').DataTable(); }`

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer by using addrow

```
var t = $('#comp-monitor').DataTable({

    });
    $("#upload").bind("click", function () {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.csv|.xlsx|.xls)$/;
        if (regex.test($("#fileUpload").val().toLowerCase())) {
            if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    var table = $("#comp-monitor tbody");
                    var rows = e.target.result.split("\n");
                    var no = 0;
                    table.empty();
                    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                        no++;
                        var row = $("<tr class='odd' role='row' />");
                        var cells = rows[i].split(",");
                            t.row.add([
                                no,
                                cells[0],
                                cells[1],
                                cells[2],
                                cells[3],
                                cells[4]
                            ]).draw(false);
                        table.append(row);
                    }
                }
                reader.readAsText($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);

            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please upload a valid CSV file.");
        }
    });
```